# Problem with ICS file, special characters and Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, special-characters, icalendar

I have a problem with an ICS file, special characters and Outlook.

When importing ICS, disappears every special character. Example:

In the file I have:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
...
...
DESCRIPTION:Some description blà blà blà
...
...
END:VCALENDAR
```

After importing into Outlook: **Some description bl bl bl**

I don't understand

Comment: What encoding is the file in? iCalendar uses UTF-8 by default.

Comment: File encoding is UTF-8. When open the ics with notepad text is in correct format. So I think that depends on the settings in Outlook.

Comment: I will try to convert special characters.

Comment: @Zaragon What did you end up doing to fix this issue?

Comment: "blà" is not a valid UTF-8 string.